# Regular expression in Python not catching all information

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
a = '''"The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore".

Said my mom, whispering.'''
```

Note the *line breaks*. In python the string will be:
`'The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore".\n    \n    Said my mom, whispering.'`

I have this regular expression: 
`pattern = u'^("|«)(.*?)("|»)(.*?)\u000A{1,}(.*?)'`

and I used as follows in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '''"The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore".

Said my mom, whispering.'''
>>> pattern = u'^("|«)(.*?)("|»)(.*?)\u000A{1,}(.*?)'
>>> re.search(pattern, a).groups()
>>> ('"', 'The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore', '"', '.', '')
```

Why the last part (`Said my mom, whispering.`) is not being caught by the regular expression? 
I'm expecting something like this:

```
>>> ('"', 'The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore', '"', '.', 'Said my mom, whispering.')
```

Can you please clarify to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The variable `a`? @vihan1086

Comment: The [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python) regex tester can be really helpful in debugging regex code.

Comment: @tegancp yes! I'm discovering it at this moment, It's helpful since it allows me to test the regex before trying it on Python!

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use this `\u000A{1,}` ? Doesn't Python have have `\n` for that ?

Comment: I found out it is actually not needed for what I want. But I thought they were equivalents so using either one would be the same, or it is not? @sln

Comment: Yeah that's fine. The `\uXXXX` construct UTF-16 is primarily used for codepoints over U+100. But encoding doesn't matter since all the chars are the same character units width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the `?` would be enough. And also it's better to include DOTALL modifier because dot in your regex by default won't match new line characters.

```
pattern = u'(?s)^("|«)(.*?)("|»)(.*?)\u000A{1,}(.*)'
```

Note that `.*?` is reluctant or non-greedy which means match any character zero or more times non-greedily. So it stops matching once it finds an empty string.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right, with: `(.*)` I will catch everything, from a space to many spaces and any other characters as well, `Greedily`, right? What's the `(?s)` for?

Comment: `.*` won't match line breaks that is newline chars by default. `(?s)` called DOTALL modifier which makes dot in out regex to match also the line breaks.

Comment: Terrific! Thank you a lot, it's a lot clearer now. Because I'll expect some line breaks on the first group and even more in the last group.

Comment: @gglasses: Note that because of the dotall mode the last `(.*)` will match everything up to the end of the string and not up to the end of the line.

Comment: The `(?s)` modifier (i.e. Dot-all) is not needed. He wants to match single line up to the `\n`, otherwise it could match newlines `(.*?)<<--here("|»)`

Comment: hmm, then he may use the negated char class `[^\n\r]*` instead of last `.*`.

Comment: @stribizhev yes! I need the first group to catch everything (including line breaks) until it finds `"` or `»`. Also with the last group. Thank you for the heads up, I'm testing everything on regex101.com

Comment: Just take off the Dot-All, then you don't need junk like this `[^\n\r]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your expression is that `(.*?)` group is *reluctant*, meaning that it shall match as little text as possible. Since you do not ask for the match to "anchor" at the end of the input, the second group is empty.

Adding `$` at the end of the regex will fix this problem:

```
pattern = u'^("|«)(.*?)("|»)(.*?)\u000A{1,}(.*?)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input does not start with the quote and regex requires it. Then, there is a missing linebreak pattern for the second line. And third, the `.*?` lazy matching will not match anything since it can match empty string so it will if you do not use an anchor $ or use a greedy matching.

Also, it is not efficient to use single letters in alternations, so I'd rather use a character class for such cases: `("|«)` => `["«]`.

With `\s` shorthand class, you can match not only linebreaks but also spaces thus "trimmimg" the results in capture groups.

Here is my suggestion:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(["«])?(.*?)(["»])?\.\s*(.*?)\s*(.*)')
test_str = "The cat is running to the door, he does not look hungry anymore\".\n\nSaid my mom, whispering."
print re.search(p, test_str).groups()
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/r3RLF2)